# Set active item in select list with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this list:

[image]

Which comes from:

```
 <select multiple size=11 ng-model="AvailableColumns" ng-show="NamesAvailable" ng-options="item for item in names">
                                    </select>
```

And the array:

```
$scope.names = ["Device Name", "Description", "Device ID", "Update Required", "Open Time", "Open Time Ada", "Opening Mode", "Timed Period Stable Id", "Automatic Change Stable Id", "Keypad Code", "Battery Status", "Last Updated"];
```

I want to know how can I select specific item in the code? For example if I want to select 'Open Time' How can I do that with AngularJS?

Comment: wanna read the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value

Comment: @Isaac I tried $scope.AvailableColumns = "Open Time Ada"; but that doesn't highlight that item for example. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `$scope.AvailableColumns  = [$scope.names[5]]`

Comment: This actually works! Thanks @Brian.

Answer (score 1):

You have a multiple select. Therefore, the default(s) should be an array, not a single value.

You can do:

```
$scope.AvailableColumns = ['Open Time Ada'];
```

Or, you can use the array position (you'll need to if you change the options to be an object vs. simple string array:

```
$scope.AvailableColumns = [$scope.names[5]];
```

So all that said, you could specify multiple items to be selected by default.